# Slick slider group navigation items with slides using data attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I am using Slick Slider JS to build out a history timeline. Each date range navigation item is connected to multiple slides using a `data-group` attribute. I am needing to adapt my code to transition the `timeline__nav ul` left or right using the previous and next buttons when the first slide with a matching `data-group` attribute slides into view.

My existing code is in the snippet below.

```js
$('.timeline__slider').slick({
  infinite: false,
  arrows: false,
  dots: false,
  autoplay: false,
  speed: 800,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 2,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 800,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    }
  }]
});

var timeLineItem = $('.timeline__nav li').css("width");
var left = $('.timeline__nav li').offset().left;

$('.js-previous-slide').click(function() {
  $('.timeline__slider').slick('slickPrev');
  // If the first timeline__item in data-group and it matches the
  // timeline__nav item's data-group attribute, animate left.
  $('.timeline__nav ul').animate({
    'left': '+=' + timeLineItem
  }, 150, function() {});
});

$('.js-next-slide').click(function() {
  $('.timeline__slider').slick('slickNext');
  // If the first timeline__item in data-group and it matches the
  // timeline__nav item's data-group attribute, animate right.
  $('.timeline__nav ul').animate({
    'left': '-=' + timeLineItem
  }, 150, function() {});
});

$('.timeline__slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  if (currentSlide === 0) {
    $('.js-previous-slide').prop('disabled', true);
    $('.js-previous-slide').addClass('is-disabled');
  } else {
    $('.js-previous-slide').prop('disabled', false);
    $('.js-previous-slide').removeClass('is-disabled');
  }

  if (slick.slideCount === currentSlide + 1) {
    $('.js-next-slide').prop('disabled', true);
    $('.js-next-slide').addClass('is-disabled');
  } else {
    $('.js-next-slide').prop('disabled', false);
    $('.js-next-slide').removeClass('is-disabled');
  }

  $('.timeline__nav li.is-active').removeClass('is-active');

  $('.slick-current .timeline__item').each(function() {
    $('.timeline__nav li[data-group="' + $(this).attr('data-group') + '"').addClass('is-active');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 1rem/1 "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #4d4d4d;
}

.section {
  margin: 0 1.25rem;
  padding: 6rem 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 6%, 1640px 0, 1640px 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 6%, 1640px 0, 1640px 100%, 0 100%);
}

.timeline {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.timeline__nav {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.timeline__nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  list-style: none;
}


/* .timeline__nav ul::after {
            content: "";
            width: 1rem;
            height: 1rem;
            position: absolute;
            top: 9px;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 2;
            background-color: #c2c2c2;
            border-radius: 50%;
        } */

.timeline__nav li {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 150ms ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .timeline__nav li {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
}

.timeline__nav li::before {
  content: "";
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #A4475B;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 100ms ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.timeline__nav li.is-active::before {
  background-color: #89102A;
  transform: scale(1.4);
}

.timeline__nav li::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #C2C2C2;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.timeline__nav li:last-child::after {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.timeline__nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2.5rem 2.5rem 0 0;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  transform: none;
  transition: color 100ms ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #A4475B;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .timeline__nav a {
    padding: 2.5rem 0 0;
  }
}

.timeline__nav li.is-active a {
  color: #89102A;
}

.timeline__slider {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.timeline__item-inner {
  padding-right: 5rem;
}

h2 {
  padding: 2rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.625rem;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1875rem;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.timeline__controls {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js"></script>
<!--Timeline-->
<section class="section">
  <div class="timeline">
    <h2>Our History</h2>
    <nav class="timeline__nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="item is-active" data-group="group1">
          <a href="#">1984 to 1988</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item" data-group="group2">
          <a href="#">1989 to 1992</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item" data-group="group3">
          <a href="#">1993 to 1999</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item" data-group="group4">
          <a href="#">2000 to 2002</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item" data-group="group5">
          <a href="#">2003 to 2005</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item" data-group="group6">
          <a href="#">2006 to 2012</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item" data-group="group7">
          <a href="#">2013 to 2020</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item" data-group="group8">
          <a href="#">2021 to 2023</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="timeline__slider">
      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group1">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1984 to 1988</h3>
          <p>
            <strong>The Early Years</strong>
          </p>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group1">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1984 to 1988</h3>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group1">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1984 to 1988</h3>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group1">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1984 to 1988</h3>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group1">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1984 to 1988</h3>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group1">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1984 to 1988</h3>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1984 to 1988 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group2">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1989 to 1992</h3>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group2">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1989 to 1992</h3>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group2">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1989 to 1992</h3>
          <p>In 1990, a grant for $175,000 was received from the federal government to build a facility, thanks to a Board member who introduced MRWC to the concept of funding applications. The 5,000 square foot facility was built with home-grade materials,
            and no blueprints or contractors. It was well ahead of most wildlife rehabilitation centres at that time and seemed far too big to ever fill. Little did we realize what was coming.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1989 to 1992 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group3">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>A 4-section, large raptor cage was built over several months for recovering birds of prey with donated labour and materials.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group3">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>A nature trail and observation tower overlooking the wetland were constructed, once again, with donated materials and labour.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group3">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>About this time, Carol assisted in the formation of the Alberta Wildlife Rehabilitators Association (AWRA).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group3">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>Requests for services began to come from many areas such as schools, organizations, members of the public, correctional institutions, foster care, and social services. MRWC kept saying “yes” to all these requests, stretching the resources and
            energy much too far.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group3">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>Funding didn't come as fast as the requests for services did, so soon debt began to build. MRWC had a banker who, when asked how to find ways to meet budget, would just approve a bigger loan.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group3">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group4">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group4">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group5">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group5">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group6">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group6">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group7">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group7">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group8">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item" data-group="group8">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->
    </div>
    <div class="timeline__controls">
      <button class="previous js-previous-slide is-disabled" disabled="">Previous</button>
      <button class="next js-next-slide">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: HI, so what doesn't work in this code

Comment: @Swati The issue is not with the existing code, but adding the functionality to connect the `data-group` attributes in the `timeline__nav` with the first slide that has a matching `data-group` attribute. I am struggling to figure this out with Slick Slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Dynamic Timeline Slick Slider

Here you go. It's nice and scalable with **dynamic grouping** and **auto-disabled** nav (when no slides correlate to the date range).

Basically, I stripped away all the data-group attributes and instead went for a dynamic approach. At initialization, the navigation is iterated and data-group attr's are applied. Then the date range is parsed and all slides evaluated to see if the date listed fits into the range. I saw that we could do a direct match (1989 to 1992 for example), but this way you could have subsets like a slide that was from 1989 to 1990 or 1990-1991 and it would still match that date range.

I also tidied up your functions a little and added in a disabled option for navigation that had no correlating date range slides.

This can be easily extended in case you have slides with just one date (1994) or a date range that spans 2 different sets (1990-2010).

```js
$('.timeline__slider').slick({
  infinite: false,
  arrows: false,
  dots: false,
  autoplay: false,
  speed: 800,
  cssEase: 'ease-in-out',
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 2,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 800,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    }
  }]
});

$('.js-previous-slide').on("click", () => moveSlide(-1));
$('.js-next-slide').on("click", () => moveSlide(1));

function moveSlide(inc) {
  if (inc > 0) $('.timeline__slider').slick('slickNext');
  else $('.timeline__slider').slick('slickPrev');
}


$('.timeline__slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  $('.js-previous-slide')
    .prop('disabled', currentSlide === 0)
    .addClass(() => currentSlide === 0 && 'is-disabled' || '')
    .removeClass(() => currentSlide !== 0 && 'is-disabled' || '')

  let isLastSlide = slick.slideCount === currentSlide + 1;
  $('.js-next-slide')
    .prop('disabled', isLastSlide)
    .addClass(() => isLastSlide && 'is-disabled' || '')
    .removeClass(() => !isLastSlide && 'is-disabled' || '')

  $('.timeline__nav li.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
  $('.timeline__nav li[data-group="' + $('.slick-current').data('group') + '"').addClass('is-active');
//console.log($('.timeline__nav ul').css('transform'))
let xAdjust = (($('.slick-current').data('group')-1) * 100);
$('.timeline__nav ul').css('transform',`translateX(-${xAdjust}px)`)
 });


// set up the timeline items with their groups
let groupNum = 1;
$('nav.timeline__nav li').each(function() {
  let [from, to] = $(this).text().trim().split('to');
  from = +from.trim();
  to = +to.trim();
  $(this).attr('data-group', groupNum);
  let dataGroup = groupNum;
  found = false
  $('.slick-slide').each(function() {
    let [ifrom, ito] = $(this).find('h3.year').text().trim().split('to');
    ifrom = +ifrom.trim();
    ito = +ito.trim();
    if (ifrom >= from && ito <= to) {
      $(this).attr('data-group', dataGroup);
      found = true
    }
  })
  if (!found) {
    $(this).addClass('disabled')
  }
  groupNum++;
})

// set up the click listener 
$('nav.timeline__nav li').click(function() {
  let match = $('.slick-slide[data-group=' + $(this).data('group') + ']')
  let slidenum = $('.slick-slide').index(match);
  if (slidenum >= 0) $('.timeline__slider').slick('slickGoTo', slidenum);
  // console.log('slidenum', slidenum, 'datag',$(this).data('group'));
})
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 1rem/1 "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #4d4d4d;
}

.section {
  margin: 0 1.25rem;
  padding: 6rem 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 6%, 1640px 0, 1640px 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 6%, 1640px 0, 1640px 100%, 0 100%);
}

.timeline {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.timeline__nav {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
 /* border: 1px solid red;*/
}

.timeline__nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  list-style: none;
}


/* .timeline__nav ul::after {
            content: "";
            width: 1rem;
            height: 1rem;
            position: absolute;
            top: 9px;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 2;
            background-color: #c2c2c2;
            border-radius: 50%;
        } */

.timeline__nav li {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 150ms ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .timeline__nav li {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
}

.timeline__nav li::before {
  content: "";
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #A4475B;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 100ms ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.timeline__nav li.is-active::before {
  background-color: #89102A;
  transform: scale(1.4);
}

.timeline__nav li::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #C2C2C2;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.timeline__nav li:last-child::after {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.timeline__nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2.5rem 2.5rem 0 0;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  transform: none;
  transition: color 100ms ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #A4475B;
}

.timeline__nav li.disabled {
  opacity: .3;
}

.timeline__nav li.disabled a {
  cursor: arrow;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .timeline__nav a {
    padding: 2.5rem 0 0;
  }
}

.timeline__nav li.is-active a {
  color: #89102A;
}

.timeline__slider {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.timeline__item-inner {
  padding-right: 5rem;
}

h2 {
  padding: 2rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.625rem;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1875rem;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.timeline__controls {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js"></script>
<!--Timeline-->
<section class="section">
  <div class="timeline">
    <h2>Our History</h2>
    <nav class="timeline__nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="item is-active">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">1984 to 1988</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">1989 to 1992</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">1993 to 1999</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">2000 to 2002</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">2003 to 2005</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">2006 to 2012</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">2013 to 2020</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">2021 to 2023</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="timeline__slider">
      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1984 to 1988</h3>
          <p>
            <strong>The Early Years</strong>
          </p>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1984 to 1988</h3>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1984 to 1988</h3>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1984 to 1988</h3>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1984 to 1988</h3>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1984 to 1988</h3>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1984 to 1988 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1989 to 1992</h3>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1989 to 1992</h3>
          <p>Sample content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1989 to 1992</h3>
          <p>In 1990, a grant for $175,000 was received from the federal government to build a facility, thanks to a Board member who introduced MRWC to the concept of funding applications. The 5,000 square foot facility was built with home-grade materials,
            and no blueprints or contractors. It was well ahead of most wildlife rehabilitation centres at that time and seemed far too big to ever fill. Little did we realize what was coming.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1989 to 1992 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>A 4-section, large raptor cage was built over several months for recovering birds of prey with donated labour and materials.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>A nature trail and observation tower overlooking the wetland were constructed, once again, with donated materials and labour.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>About this time, Carol assisted in the formation of the Alberta Wildlife Rehabilitators Association (AWRA).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>Requests for services began to come from many areas such as schools, organizations, members of the public, correctional institutions, foster care, and social services. MRWC kept saying “yes” to all these requests, stretching the resources and
            energy much too far.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>Funding didn't come as fast as the requests for services did, so soon debt began to build. MRWC had a banker who, when asked how to find ways to meet budget, would just approve a bigger loan.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->

      <!--Timeline item-->
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__image">
        </div>
        <div class="timeline__item-inner">
          <h3 class="year">1993 to 1999</h3>
          <p>In 1995, a full time Education Coordinator was hired, and the formal on-site and off-site programs increased.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Timeline item-->
      <!-- End 1993 to 1999 -->
    </div>
    <div class="timeline__controls">
      <button class="previous js-previous-slide is-disabled" disabled="">Previous</button>
      <button class="next js-next-slide">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your code does enable grouping of slides and connecting them with the nav item dates, but it does not address the left and right transition of the nav items using the previous/next buttons. Why did you use the `h3.year` element instead of matching the data groups? It seems like unnecessary additional code.

Comment: @MikeHermary - Sorry I missed the next/prev buttons! They're accomodated in my updated answer. This code _does_ match data groups. The only difference is - rather than hard code the data groups up front, the script does it for you. Why? because that gives you flexibility - like for instance if later on you decide to add 1980 to 1984 .. or subdivide 1993 to 1999 into 1993 to 1996 _and_ 1997 to 1999. You could just add that html (without having to reorder your groups) and the code would adjust.  It uses h3.year to establish group order when it init's but thereafter it uses `data-group`.

Comment: It does add some extra code to do this, but I believe it's benefits are significant, and it's a good coding pattern, freeing the content from the logic a bit. Plus I did remove a decent amount of extra code in the other functions. Pls let me know if any of this requires explanation

Comment: I like this answer, I also think this would be an even more complete solution if when you click prev-next that the timeline navigation also updates.

Comment: @EspressoBeans - thanks. It does update, but not until you reach a slide from a different date-range. there are many slides in a given date range (corresponding to the nav)

Comment: @Kinglish ah ok, got it.  very complete solution.

Comment: @MikeHermary - what do you say? Does my clean code and helpful service win me the answer + bounty? I'm really happy with this and wonder if you're pleased as well.

Comment: @Kinglish Sorry, I have been super busy this week with other work. I will review and test your updated code in the next couple of days, and respond accordingly.

Comment: @Kinglish I have tested your code and I am having issues with transitioning the `.timeline_nav ul` when the previous/next buttons or `timeline__nav` links are clicked. This code `$('.timeline__nav ul').css({transform: 'translateX(-100px)'});` only triggers on the initial click, then nothing afterwards. Is an `.each` statement needed?

Comment: @MikeHermary - ok that is fixed and working. The thing is, using transform:translateX is working fine, but that css works independently of the overflow-x scroll, meaning that the scroller on that nav doesn't work. I removed the css rule 'overflow-x:auto' for this reason. if you go and enable it you'll see what I mean. If you want to keep that overflow-x scroll, then we'll need to use another method to move the UL around. Personally I find the scrollbar an unwelcome UI so I favor the method in this revised answer.

Comment: @Kinglish I have tested your updated code and all seems to be working as expected. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeHermary - so glad to hear it! Unfortunately the original +50 bounty you placed on this question expired unrewarded. Would you be able to grant that after the fact?

Comment: @Kinglish I can reward the bounty, but I am not sure where to do that.

Comment: @MikeHermary According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work - (search for Can I offer a second bounty after the first one has expired) - you can create a new bounty (the old one you had expired and is gone forever), but the caveat is it has to be twice what the old one was. You may have to 'unaccept' the answer first and find a 'start a bounty' link. Otherwise, I am not sure.

Comment: @MikeHermary I looked at this page and it seems like this is the only way... but it's not clear: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292590/bounty-created-to-reward-existing-answer-only-one-answer-exists-bounty-expired